# Node.js/Stripe API | Product Creation not working when using (err, product)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, stripe-payments

Currently, I am trying to be able to create a new stripe product with the given details from the form data I will input.  So far when creating the stripe product it will and give me the product details in console.log(product) only if I do not use the commented out section which I would like to be able to use.  If I use the commented out section then it will say product is undefined, and I am unable to pass an undefined stripeID. I will also take any tips about the code in general as I am still learning! Thank you!

```
 //Product Create
        app.post('/products', async (req, res) => {
        
          // Creates New Stripe Product
          const product = await stripe.products.create({
            name: req.body.productName,
            images: [req.body.productImage]
            /*     }, 
                (err, newProduct) => {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  } else {
                    console.log(`New Stripe Product Created`);
                  }  */ 
          });

          console.log(product);
        
          // Creates product with stripe Id and adds it to Mongo DB
          Product.create({
              productName: req.body.productName,
              productDescription: req.body.productDescription,
              price: req.body.productPrice,
              img: req.body.productImage,
              stripeProductId: product.id
            },
            (err, newProduct) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log('product not added to mongo');
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                console.log('product created');
              }
            });
        
          res.send('New/Post Create New Product');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using 2 approaches i.e. `await` as well as callbacks, when calling those methods.

1. Here's how the `await` approach should look:

```
const product = await stripe.products.create({
    name: req.body.productName,
    images: [req.body.productImage]
});
console.log("My product is" , product);
```

2. And your callback approach would look different, you would be logging `newProduct` inside the callback:

```
stripe.products.create({
    name: req.body.productName,
    images: [req.body.productImage]
}, 
    (err, newProduct) => {
        console.log("I am here");
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('New Stripe Product Created', newProduct);
    }
});
```